# Python: Nested for loop is extremely slow - reading RLE compressed 3D data

Tags: python, performance

I need to read 3D data compressed with run-length encoding (RLE) into a 3D numpy array in python. In Matlab this takes around a second using a nested loop. However in python this takes 48 seconds!

This is my code:

```
# Preallocate 3D voxel grid
vox_size = [200,150,200];
voxelGrid3D = np.zeros([200,150,200], dtype=np.uint32);

# Get values from RLE encoded 3D scene: 
# Example:
# 0, (3), 4, (2) --> corresponds to --> 00044 
# --> value == [0, 4]
# --> value_reps == [3, 2]
value = labelsRleCompressed[::2];
value_reps = labelsRleCompressed[1::2];

vox_idx = 0;
vox_idx_all = 0;
num_elements = value_reps.size; # Number of elements to convert
for m in np.arange(0,num_elements):
    numReps = value_reps[m];
    currentValue = value[m];
    for l in np.arange(0,numReps):
    # Compute respective grid indices
        i = (np.floor(vox_idx_all / (vox_size[0] * vox_size[1]) ) % vox_size[2]);
        j = (np.floor(vox_idx_all / (vox_size[0]) ) % vox_size[1]);
        k = (np.floor(vox_idx_all ) % vox_size[0]);

    # Fill grid with label value
        voxelGrid3D[i,j,k] = currentValue;
        vox_idx_all = vox_idx_all + 1;
```

Even if I remove the inner loop and replace it with precomputed grid indices + reshape function the whole process still takes 10 seconds!

```
voxelGrid = np.zeros(num_voxels,dtype=np.uint32)
repIter = 0;
numReps = 0;
vox_idx = 0;
for counter in np.arange(0,num_voxels):
    if repIter == numReps:
        numReps = value_iter[vox_idx];
        currentValue = value[vox_idx];
        vox_idx = vox_idx + 1;
        voxelGrid[counter] = currentValue
        repIter = 1;
    else:
        voxelGrid[counter] = currentValue
        repIter = repIter + 1;
voxelGrid3D = np.reshape(voxelGrid,(vox_size[0],vox_size[1],vox_size[2]))
```

This is much too slow for my application. Has anyone an idea how to make this even faster?

Comment: Python is a quick, easy to learn, high-level programming language. Worse yet, it's an interpreted language. If you want speed, go with a compiled language. For this particular task, basic C would be just fine.

Comment: Hmm, I thought about interfacing Python with C++ (boost python) and looking for libraries that deal with reading RLE encoded 3D data, but so far no luck... I will post a solution if I can find one

Answer (score 0):

**Speed up loops**

At first don't use np.arange to create an iterator (this will create an array on which you iterate over). Use range (Python3) or xrange (Python2) instead. This should increase the performane by a few percent, but isn't your real bottleneck here.

Matlab has a just in time compiler to perform relativly good in loops, CPython doesn't have this by default. But there is a just in time compiler called numba http://numba.pydata.org/ . In the documentation you will find supported functions that can be compiled to native machine code. When using numba I would also recommend to write things in loops instead of vectorised code, because this is easier to handle for the compiler.

I have modified your code a bit.

```
def decompress_RLE(labelsRleCompressed,vox_size):
    res=np.empty(vox_size[0]*vox_size[1]*vox_size[2],np.uint32)

    ii=0
    for i in range(0,labelsRleCompressed.size,2):
        value=labelsRleCompressed[i]
        rep=labelsRleCompressed[i+1]
        for j in range(0,rep):
            res[ii]=value
            ii=ii+1

    res=res.reshape((vox_size[0],vox_size[1],vox_size[2]))

    return res
```

**Create data for benchmarking**

```
vox_size=np.array((300,300,300),dtype=int32)
#create some data
labelsRleCompressed=np.random.randint(0, 500, 
size=vox_size[0]*vox_size[1]*vox_size[2]/2, dtype=np.uint32)
labelsRleCompressed[1::2]=4
```

Simply calling the function with the generated data results in a runtime of **7.5** seconds, which is a rather poor performance.

Now let's use numba.

```
import numba
nb_decompress_RLE = numba.jit("uint32[:,:,:](uint32[:],int32[:])",nopython=True)(decompress_RLE) #stick to the datatypes written in the decorator
```

Calling the compiled nb_decompress_RLE with the test data results in a runtime of **0.0617** seconds. A nice speed up by a factor of 119! Simple copying an array with np.copy is only 3 times faster.